# Trigger order of execution

Tags: postgresql

I prepared a dumb-proof rollback memu on order to give possibility to rollback wrong commands. It works such a Ctrl-Z. To do this I prepared the log tables that contains all the operations done. The rollback menu, group the operation for transaction, and shows   all tables. Therefore there is so much UNION as number of tables, and GROUP BY nested inside another query where are given some infos of the fields to recognize the operation done.And is all stored in a view. Nothing to say that the size of the log tsbles, the several unions that doesn't allow to put LIMIT and ORDER statment between them makes the query not efficient. I am thinking to produce also the rollback menu with a table filled by a Trigger FOR EACH STATMENT. Catched AFTER action. The log tables catches the BEFORE. But I must be sure that the action EACH STATMENT is fired after that all rows are inserted/deleted etc. In order to have the ammount of records involved in the transaction and other infos. Are the EACH STATMENT trigger fired at the very end of transaction, or get fired with  the first row or randomly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

`Statement-level BEFORE triggers naturally fire before the statement starts to do anything, while statement-level AFTER triggers fire at the very end of the statement.`

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/trigger-definition.html

In other words, a before statement trigger will be run just before the statement executes, and an after statement trigger will be run just after the statement finishes executing.

Statement level triggers can't be constraint triggers, and only constraint triggers are deferrable, so there's no way to postpone the trigger until the end of the transaction.

If more than one trigger needs to run at a given time, they are run
in the alphabetical order of their name.

Comment: Thanks, I read a lot of times all the documentation about, and never found this page.